# Any third party tool for image editor in asp.net?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

i want to add image editor in my website..
I am unable to find any solution
if any third party plugin available 
then please let me know...

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

See if these helps:

**[RadImageEditor](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/imageeditor/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx)**

**[ImageStudio](http://imagestudio.codeplex.com/)**

**[Image Upload and Editor Control](http://imageeditor.codeplex.com/)**

**[Photo Editor for asp.net](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/313574/Photo-Editor-for-asp-net-website)**